# PriorityBlockingDeque/PriorityDeque implementation

Tags: java, collections, deque

I'm looking for a PriorityBlockingDeque(or even a PriorityDeque) implementation since the Java doesn't provide one with the standard library.

Thanks.

Addition: Forgot to mention, any library in addition to [infomancers-collections](http://code.google.com/p/infomancers-collections)

Comment: You might find [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/index.html) useful.

Specifically, the [Priority Buffer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/PriorityBuffer.html) may be what you are after.

Comment: PriorityBuffer doesn't look like a Deque...

Comment: Very relevant question for use in akka + stash + priority mailbox, which is not an unreasonable use case with for instance akka persistence

Answer (score 2):

Guava: [`MinMaxPriorityQueue`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html).  Not blocking -- but if you like, you can file a feature request for such a beast.

Comment: I need a PriorityDeque, preferable PriorityBlockingDeque

Comment: I'm not sure even what a PriorityDeque is supposed to be.  Are you supposed to be able to pull out the minimum and maximum priorities, or something else?

Comment: Yes please. What is the difference? We have been considering renaming MMPQ to PriorityDeque.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to google with "PriorityBlockingDeque java".

First refererence is seems to be [what you want](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=PriorityBlockingDeque%20java&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/infomancers-collections/source/browse/trunk/Collections/src/com/infomancers/collections/concurrent/PriorityBlockingDeque.java?spec=svn87&r=87&ei=a_EOT9DWKonV4QTk2fnEAw&usg=AFQjCNEAACMxcm-GqgEGGPXpP8jSTokMQw).

Google is our friend ;)

Comment: Indeed, I already saw that one :) I should have mention it so answers will bring something new on the table :)